# Angular 2 - Mocking Services in Components that depend on other services

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-jasmine

How do I mock a service that depends on another service that is in a component?
Please check code below.

**a.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  providers: [ MyServiceA ]
})
export class MyComponent {
```

**my-service-a.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class MyServiceA{
  constructor(private myServiceB: MyServiceB) {}
```

**my-service-b.service.ts**

```
export class MyServiceB{
constructor(private myServiceC: MyServiceC,
              private myServiceD: MyServiceD) {}
```

How do I mock the service in the **a.component.spec.ts** in the TestBed configuration? Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can mock it however you want. The other services don't matter. I think maybe the problem you are facing is with the `@Component.providers`. Using this, any mocks you configure in the `TestBed` aren't used as the `@Component.providers` take precedence, causing Angular to try to create it, instead of using the mock.

To get around that, Angular offers the `TestBed.overrideComponent` method, so that we can override things like the template and providers of the `@Component`

```
beforeEach(() => {
  let myMockService = new MyMockService();

  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
      // the following will not be used
      { provide: MyService, useValue: myMockService }
    ]
  });
  TestBed.overrideComponent(MyComponent, {
    set: {
      providers: [
        // this will override the @Component.providers:[MyService]
        { provide: MyService, useValue: myMockService }
      ]
    }
  });
})
```